# Problema con Container-fluid con imagenes

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Cuando coloco una imagen dentro de un `<div class="container-fluid">`, la imagen siempre me sale con un pequeño margen en la izquierda, si se supone que el `container-fluid` no contiene márgenes. La única forma de que no me aparezca es no colocando la clase de Bootstrap 4.

Coloco un código sencillo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Imagen 1</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <img src="http://cursosformacionseguros.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/fondoAtenci%C3%B3n-y-fidelizaci%C3%B3n-de-clientes-en-redes-sociales-en-seguros.-Social-CRM-y-social-loyalty-en-seguros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Es un código sencillo, pero lo he hecho en otras páginas y la única solución, como dije anteriormente, es quitándole la clase de Bootstrap.

Comment: Recuerda el orden que se establece en la documentación de bootstrap: contenedor, fila, columnas. En tu código estás omitiendo la fila. Ahora si lo que deseas es que la imagen ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla hazlo con css y background-zise: cover;

Comment: Si no vas a meter filas y columnas no es necesario que uses container-fluid.

Comment: ami me funciono quitandolo la clase container-fluid tampoco use container,y solo use un div y funciona y esta responsive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La clase `container-fluid` como tal no incluye márgenes pero **sí** incluye padding:

```
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Curiosamente, la documentación oficial de Bootstrap sugiere NO utilizar ni `.container` ni `.container-fluid` si se desea ocupar el ancho completo del viewport. [Fuente](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters)

Por último se sugiere mantener la estructura de filas y columnas típica de Bootstrap, en el ejemplo utilizo la grilla de flexbox

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Imagen 1</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <img src="http://cursosformacionseguros.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/fondoAtenci%C3%B3n-y-fidelizaci%C3%B3n-de-clientes-en-redes-sociales-en-seguros.-Social-CRM-y-social-loyalty-en-seguros.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues hace un rato, me he estado peleando con algo muy parecido, en un container-fluid me he encontrado con un scroll horizontal, he estado probando y todo venia de 15px de margin left y right.
Mi estructura era esta:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <row>
        <col-sm-6></col-sm-6>
        <col-sm-6></col-sm-6>
    </row>
</div>
```

Los margenes solo salian al meter las col en esa estructura, asi que lo solucione poniendo la siguiente clase a la row:

.reset-margin {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}